# distinct description

Tags: mysql, select, greatest-n-per-group, distinct

I have the following database:

```
id | remote_id | title | description
-------------------------------------
1  | 12341234  | test  | test-description
2  | 4535234   | blah  | testestetetst
3  | 12341234  | test  | test-description2
4  | 3454656   | qsffq | testqfsfqgfgsdffgfd
```

I'm trying to select the description (and ONLY the description) of each unique remote_id. The 'winning' description should be the highest id. like this:

```
id | remote_id | title | description
-------------------------------------
2  | 4535234   | blah  | testestetetst
3  | 12341234  | test  | test-description2
4  | 3454656   | qsffq | testqfsfqgfgsdffgfd
```

using the following code returns each unique remote_id correctly

```
SELECT DISTINCT(remote_id) FROM table ORDER BY id DESC
```

but this returns the duplicates

```
SELECT DISTINCT(remote_id),description FROM table ORDER BY id DESC
```

How do can I filter distinct values on remote_id, but only select the description with the highest id in my query?

any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT 1: formatting

EDIT 2: using following version: 5.7.27-0ubuntu0.18.04.1

Comment: What is your MySQL server version ? Run `SELECT version();` and report the result of this query please.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya using 5.7.27-0ubuntu0.18.04.1

Comment: `distinct` is not a function, and it applies to all columns in the select list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html) (subquery) and get all the maximum `id` values for every unique `remote_id` value. We can then `JOIN` this subquery  to the original table to get the rows corresponding to highest `id`.

```
SELECT 
  t.*
FROM table_name AS t 
JOIN (SELECT 
        remote_id, 
        MAX(id) AS max_id 
      FROM table_name
      GROUP BY remote_id) AS dt 
  ON dt.remote_id = t.remote_id 
     AND dt.max_id = t.id
```

---

Another way is to use a [Correlated Subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/correlated-subqueries.html) inside the `WHERE` clause. We will get the `Max()` id value for every `remote_id` and match against the same.

```
SELECT 
  t.*
FROM table_name AS t 
WHERE t.id = (SELECT MAX(t2.id) 
              FROM table_name AS t2 
              WHERE t2.remote_id = t.remote_id)
```

Comment: I used the subquery inside the WHERE clause, and it works like a charm. Thanks!